# From Illustrator to Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have a illustrator file with base shapes for a icon i'm creating and I want to go to photoshop now.

The task is simple: Start a new photoshop document with all the Illustrator's shapes as vector masks in photoshop.

How can I do that? Is there a simple way? There's a lot of shapes, and i don't want to drag and drop each of them in Photoshop because they don't go in place. This means, if I copy and paste each one, i'll need to move them to the right position too, and it will take too much work.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to take this into Photoshop? What is the exact *design* problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple, automated way.  You're pretty much stuck with either re-positioning or re-coloring your shapes unless you can use a Smart Object.

I personally lean towards re-coloring.  To do so, copy all of your shapes in Illustrator and paste them into Photoshop as a new Shape Layer.  This layer will have all the shapes in their appropriate locations.  You can then copy each shape to a new layer and re-color.  It's cumbersome, but you won't have to reposition anything.

The alternative is to paste into Photoshop as a Smart Object.  This will, in effect, place your AI art as a single layer in Photoshop.  When you double-click the layer to edit the shapes, it will allow you to edit the objects in Illustrator.  If you do not need the shapes to be their own layers in Photoshop, this may be your best bet.